# Leaving temporarily

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I'm looking for a word or expression to convey the meaning of "leaving *temporarily*".

**Context**: I'm writing house rules for a bed & breakfast, and I want to ask guests to turn off the lights every time they go out of their room.

Specifically, I want a clear way to distinguish between leaving the room and checking out. If I say "please turn off the lights when you leave", they might construe it as "please turn off the lights when you check out".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Please conserve energy and turn off the lights when you are out of the room." And if your clientele tends to be environmentally conscious, you might add a phrase that it also lowers carbon emissions and fights global warming.

Comment: Thanks. The phrasing "when you are out of the room" sidesteps the problem of ambiguity.